# Check is the groups $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{C}^*, \cdot)$ are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have to check if the groups $(\mathbb{R}, +)$ and $(\mathbb{C}^*, \cdot)$ are isomorphic.

I kept trying different functions to see if I can guess one that shows that the $2$ groups are isomorphic, but I didn't find any such function. How can I approach this?

Because we have the group $(\mathbb{C}^*, \cdot)$, I thought that I could use the fact that an an isomorphic function between $2$ groups has the property $f(e_1) = e_2$, where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the identity elements of the first, respectively, the second group. But again, I can't progress any further.

Is there a general approach to use if I want to check whether two groups are isomorphic or not? Is there a straightforward way of proving that two groups are **NOT** isomorphic, or that they are? I've never done problems like this before and it feels a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is look at the orders of elements. $\mathbb{C}^*$  has infinitely many elements of finite order, $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't any element of finite order other than zero.

Comment: Interesting. So you're saying that if the number of elements with finite/infinite order from one group is different than the number of elements with finite/infinte order from the other group then the two groups cannot be isomorphic? Did I understand that right? If so, what is the logic behind it? Can you explain a bit, or link me to a resource where I can read about it?

Comment: Yes you got it right! The intuitive idea is that two objects that are isomorphic are  "the same", not equal but the same  in the sense they share the same properties, like the order, the commutativity, and anything else...

Comment: Formally if $f:G\to H$ is an isomorphism, then $f$ preserves the order of elements. If $o(a)=k$ then $o(f(a))=k$, and vice-versa. You can check it easily.

Comment: But can $0$ be considered an element of finite order in $(\mathbb{R}, +)$? Is it considered an element of finite order? I know that the order would be the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $n \cdot a = 0$ but since $a$ itself is zero, $n$ can be anything. So what is $n$ then? Do we simply consider it to be $1$, the smallest number from $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Answer (score 0):

The groups are not isomorphic. This is because $(-1)^2=1 \in \mathbb{C}^*$, but there is no nonzero real number $x$ for which $2x=0$.

Comment: But why does that prove that the two groups are not isomorphic? I don't understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: If they were isomorphic, there must exist a a bijection $f: \mathbb C^* \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(c_1c_2)=f(c_1)+f(c_2)$ $\forall c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb C^*$. Setting $c_1=c_2=1$, we get $f(1)=f(1) + f(1)$ which implies $f(1)=0$. If we set $c_1=c_2=-1$, we get $0=f(1)=f(-1)+f(-1)$, which implies that $f(-1)=0$ is also true. But then $f$ can't be a bijection.